# How does std::unordered_map actually use hash functions?

Tags: c++, hash

It is not very clear to me how the standard `std::unordered_map` container uses hashing.

I am pretty new to hashing, and right now I'm trying to pass my university data structure exams.

I understand that if I have a collection of objects, I have to group their keys as random as possible by a criteria so that they lie as uniformly as possible in some buckets, and I can afterwards search/insert/delete in constant time by looking into the bucket associated with the hashed key (this is mainly what hashing with chaining does, correct me if I am wrong).

But, how does `std::unordered_map` use hashing? How does it set a new (key, value) pair using hashing? I mean, I know that hashing will group the keys by some criteria, but it is not clear at all how it sets a new (key, value) pair using hashing.

Comment: You have the full source code in your compiler's include directory.  In the case of VC++, the algorithm is in <xhash>  Note that "value" is not involved in the hash -- only "key" matters.

Comment: To understand hash-tables, have a look at [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most standard library containers, the answer would be: However it feels like, it's an implementation detail left up to the writer of the library.

However, `unordered_map` is a little peculiar in that respect because it not only has to behave in a certain way, but it also has contraints applied to how it's implemented.

From the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#general-9

> The elements of an unordered associative container are organized into buckets. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket. The number of buckets is automatically increased as elements are added to an unordered associative container, so that the average number of elements per bucket is kept below a bound. Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements. For unordered_­multiset and unordered_­multimap, rehashing preserves the relative ordering of equivalent elements.

In short, the map has `N` buckets at any given time. The result of the hash function is used to pick a bucket by doing something along the lines of `bucket_id = hash_value % N`. If the buckets start to get too "full", the map will increase `N`, and reorganize its contents.

How are things organized within a bucket is not really specified. It's typically a linked list.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. My teacher used to tell us that python dictionaries and c++ ```std::unordered_map``` use hashing as it was the most basic thing ever, and I just thought it's something that I'm missing. So the things are not so simple and clear...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know what a hash-table is, I didn't know how exactly it is used in the implementation of ```std::unordered_map```.

Comment: @Johnny: Are you aware that `std::unordered_map` _is_ literally just a weirdly named hashtable?